# Was this undocumented RAISERROR syntax ever documented and subsequently deprecated?

Tags: sql-server, error-handling

I'm working on a large SQL Server codebase, some of which has been in development since at least SQL 7 and possibly before.

Throughout the codebase, the method of raising an error is to use the following syntax which is, as far as I can tell, undocumented

```
RAISERROR <error number> <error message>
```

The `error number` can be any value greater than 13000; no corresponding entry needs to exist in the `sys.messages` table. The `error message` can also be arbitrary.

The following sample code

```
raiserror 13000 'test error'
```

produces the following output

```
Msg 13000, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
test error
```

This behaviour is the same in SQL 2000, 2005 and 2008 (I haven't tested 2008 R2).

We're going to attempt to standardise on a supported method, but my question is where this behaviour came from in the first place.

I assume this must once have been documented, supported behaviour, but copies of books online for SQL 7 and before are difficult to find. Does anybody know when this was supported or when it was deprecated, if ever?

**Edit**
To clarify, according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx), the supported `RAISERROR` syntax is

```
RAISERROR ( { msg_id | msg_str | @local_variable }
    { ,severity ,state }
    [ ,argument [ ,...n ] ] )
    [ WITH option [ ,...n ] ]
```

And any user error number which is not defined in `sys.messages` should be raised with an error message id of 50000

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This looks like it *might* be a throwback to SQL Server's origins in Sybase, whose `RAISERROR` command has this exact syntax:

- [SyBooks Online – Sybase IQ 15.2 > Reference: Statements and Options > SQL Statements – RAISERROR statement [T-SQL]](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1520/html/iqrefso/X315759.htm)

Whatever its origins, this syntax is deprecated as of SQL Server 2008 R2 and will be removed in SQL Server 2012 (v 11.*x*). See the [Deprecated Database Engine Features in SQL Server 2008 R2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729(v=sql.105).aspx) page for details.

Answer (score 0):

A user defined error message is actually ***from*** 13000 through to 2147483647.

So the behaviour you are describing is correct - you are raising a user defined error.

Comment: Agreed - but the syntax is not documented, and according to the docs, any user error not defined in `sys.messages` should be raised with an error code of 50000