# RAISERROR Syntax error in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

I'm working on migrating SQL Server 2008 R2 database to SQL Server 2014. Having trouble with the following trigger. Looks like something with `RAISEERROR` is not supported in newer version.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Route_ITrig] 
ON [dbo].[Route] 
FOR INSERT AS
    /*
     * PREVENT NULL VALUES IN 'RouteName'
     */
    IF (SELECT Count(*) FROM inserted WHERE RouteName IS NULL) > 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR 44444 'Field ''RouteName'' cannot contain a null value.'
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
```

This is the error I'm getting

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Route_ITrig, Line 15
>   Incorrect syntax near '44444'

Comment: Add parentheses `raiseerror ( ... )`

Comment: @juergend already tried that but no luck.

Comment: check this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql

Comment: It should be `RAISERROR (44444,-1,-1,'Field ''RouteName'' cannot contain a null value.') `

Comment: Don't - just don't. Change the column to not allow nulls and you're done - no trigger needed. In addition, "tried that ... no luck" is not a helpful comment.Try reading the documentation first to understand the changed syntax - you cannot provide an error number **AND** a user-defined message - you are migrating from very old syntax/compatibility.

Comment: Related link about syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749962/was-this-undocumented-raiserror-syntax-ever-documented-and-subsequently-deprecat

Answer (score 1):

This is a SQL function, hence all required variables must be passed in brackets, as follows:

```
RAISERROR(44444, 'Field ', 'RouteName', ' cannot contain a null value.')
```